# Find cross-package dependencies between yarn workspaces

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg

Having multi-module TypeScript codebase living in monorepo and linked together using yarn workspaces.
Root package.json declares each module as a workspace and dependency.

```
  {
    ...
    "workspaces": [
      "mod1",
      "mod2",
      "mod3",
      "mod4"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
      "mod1": "*",
      "mod2": "*",
      "mod3": "*",
      "mod4": "*"
    }
  }
```

In this setup there is no need to declare dependencies in each module's `package.json` and codebase has lots of cross-package imports like `import {svc} from 'mod1'`.

Is there a tool to analyze all code imports and extract cross-package dependencies between yarn workspaces?

```
mod1 -> mod2
 |
 v
mode3 -> mod4
```